# how to obtain .graphql file from GraphQLSchema javascript object?

Tags: javascript, graphql, relayjs, graphql-js

I am creating a new graphQL schema with [graphql-js](https://github.com/graphql/graphql-js) but is not going to be served through http, is going to be used as a local graphql service. I need to obtain the schema for this graphql in json format to merge it with another schema. I have been using [get-graphql-schema](https://github.com/graphcool/get-graphql-schema) to obtain the schema from a server, but this is not going to work in my case.

What I would like is to obtain the json with the schema from the `GraphQLSchema` object that I obtain after make `new GraphQLSchema({ query, mutation });`

I'm sure that is quite simple but I'm a bit stuck with that. Thank you!

Comment: Why is `get-graphql-schema` not feasible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you want a .graphql file from a `GraphQLSchema` object created locally you can just use `printSchema` to print it then write it to a file

```
import { printSchema } from 'graphql';
import Query from './Query';
import fs from 'fs';

const schema = new GraphQLSchema({
  query: Query
});

const fileData = printSchema(schema);

fs.writeFile('/path/to/schema.graphql', fileData, error => {
  // handle error
});
```

the `get-graphql-schema` package can only be used with a `graphql-server` endpoint. That package first sends an introspection query to get the JSON representation, then reconstructs a client (non-executable) schema using `graphql-js` 
 `buildClientSchema` then uses `printSchema` to finally output the schema language representation  that can be put in a .graphql file. Since you already have the `GraphQLSchema` object locally you can just skip the first 2 steps and print the schema.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [get-graphql-schema](https://github.com/graphcool/get-graphql-schema) on your localhost graphql server.

Comment: He specifically said that package wouldnt work for him

Comment: @vbranden Maybe I misunderstood.. Aren't you @Fernando trying to get the graphql schema that you are serving from localhost in json format? If so, why `get-graphql-schema` wouldn't suit your needs?

Comment: because he is trying to create the .graphql file from a local `GraphQLSchema` object, not a graphql server endpoint. `get-graphql-schema` requires an endpoint.

Comment: @vbranden Ok sorry, I thought by **local graphql service** he meant a localhost server